# Use of __getattr__ results in TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to define a simple class and instance in Python 2.7, but I'm running into trouble with __getattr__. Minimal working example below:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.a = value

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return 'hello'

class MyOtherClass:

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.a = value

MyInstance = MyClass(6)

MyOtherInstance = MyOtherClass(6)
```

Now if I enter `dir(MyInstance)` I get:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

But if I enter `dir(MyOtherInstance)` I get:

```
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'a']
```

Likewise if I enter `MyInstance` I get:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

But if I enter `MyOtherInstance` I get:

```
<__main__.MyOtherClass instance at 0x0000000003458648>
```

The behaviour with `MyOtherInstance` is what I expect. Why am I not getting this behaviour with `MyInstance`?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on Python 3.x , haven't tried 2.x

Comment: First guess: bad interaction with `__getattr__` and the fact that `MyClass` is an old-style class.

Comment: The problem goes away if you use `class MyClass(object):` instead. Moral of the story: don't use old-style classes.

Comment: Thanks. This is the first I've heard of old style classes. Can you link any resources on old versus new style classes?

Comment: @FinrodFelagund If you have a choice, stick with Python 3 and don't worry about old-style classes; they only exist in Python 2. Even in Python 2, you shouldn't use them; always inherit from `object` (or another known new-style class).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python/16193572.

Comment: Note: If you must use Python 2, a slightly easier approach to getting new-style classes than explicitly inheriting from `object` every time is to put `__metaclass__ = type` at the top of every source file you write (after any `__future__` imports, but at top level, before any class definitions). That does nothing on Python 3 (completely ignored), but makes all classes defined afterwards in that module implicitly new-style on Python 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `MyClass` is an old-style class (i.e., it doesn't inherit explicitly from `object` or another new-style class), which means `__getattr__` is being used for magic methods that *don't* trigger a call to `__getattr__` in new-style classes.

To see this, change your class to

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.a = value

    def __getattr__(self,name):
        print("Looking up %s" % (name,))
        return 'hello'
```

The bare use of `MyInstance` triggers a call to `MyInstance.__repr__`, but `__repr__` evaluates to the string `'hello'`, not the class's `__repr__` method.

```
>>> MyInstance
Looking up __repr__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Similarly, `dir(MyInstance)` triggers a call to `MyClass.__dir__`, and `__dir__` likewise is the string `'hello'`, not the appropriate method.

```
>>> dir(MyInstance)
Looking up __dir__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

You don't have the same problem with `MyOtherClass` because you didn't override `__getattr__`.

Inheriting from `object` makes the problem go away; magic methods are looked up separately before falling back to `__getattr__`.

```
class MyClass(object):
```